# Flutter links then firebase write

Tags: flutter, firebase, hyperlink, share

I'm creating a shopping list app using flutter and Firebase database where users can  share their own shopping list.
I'd that users can share a link where other users just tapping that link can open my app and see the shopping list shared.
So when a user tap the link automatically my app opens up and write a key value in firebase database.
How can I achieve my purpose?
I don't even know what to search in google? :s

Thank you

Comment: `I don't even know what to search in google? :s` Lol. I suggest storing each users shopping list as a unique document. Then access each document via a unique ID. For the link, try Deep linking for google flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is (within Firebase) achieved by the product called [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links). With these you can generate a link to any screen in your app, so that when the user clicks the link they are taken to that screen (even if they have to install the app first).

So I recommend reading the documentation on [creating dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/create) and [receiving dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive) in Flutter.

Comment: Thanks,and for updating a value inside Firebase db:
is it correct to call the update function inside the initstate() of the page just opened?

Comment: Whether that correct depends on many things we can't know (and you probably don't know yet either), but that'd be a good place to start.